# Archi vs trop vs hyper

Tags: sens, langage-informel

C’est quoi la différence entre ces synonymes pour « très » ? Est-ce qu’il y a des nuances différentes en entre eux ? Et à part « trop » (ce qui est SUPER courant) est-ce qu’ils sont courants ?

Comment: 'archi-' et 'hyper-' sont des préfixes, contrairement à 'trop'.

Answer (score 8):

*Archi* exprime une idée de superlatif (*cette expression est archi utilisée*) et est principalement utilisé pour exprimer un rang hiérarchique supérieur (*archidruide*, *archevêque*…)

*Trop* exprime une idée de grandeur mais qui dépasse une limite, plus qu'il n'en faudrait (*je n'en peux plus, c'en est trop !*)

*Hyper* indique un niveau supérieur (*hypersonique*) ou un excès (*hypertension*, *hyperactif*…) ce qui rejoint l'idée de « trop ».

Comment: Je pense que l'OP sous-entendait l'emploi de `trop` en tant que synonyme de `très`: "ce chat est trop mignon !"

Comment: Oui j'ai bien compris la question, je voulais juste exprimer les nuances entre chacun des synonymes, on peut tout à fait dire "un chat hyper/trop/Archi mignon", mais je pense que c'est un abus de langage, si l'on s'en tient au sens premier de chaque terme.

Comment: "archi-utilisé " est-il correct ? "hyper-sympa" est-il correct ? Les deux expressions font partie du langage courant, mais sont grammaticalement discutables.